# Vue - automatic API call based on URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I came across a pattern I never heard of today.
I've seen a Vue application with a front end mirroring the back end, meaning that:

```
xyz.com/customers/customer_id
```

Is automatically routed to a request to:

```
xyz.com/backend/customers/customer_id
```

before the component loads. 
This is utterly annoying because you can't mock components easily without disabling either the route guard (which disables all the components that are already dependent on the response) or resort to always prioritize the backend before even trying ideas on the front end. Also if I had a component that only displays a local img, I'm tied in having a request sent to the server for no purpose.
I only considered a safe option (up to now) leveraging lifecycle hooks to load data.
Is this even a pattern? 
Has this some utility that I have missed?

Thanks. If the question is too open, notify me and I'll take it down, but I couldn't find anything on the subject, if this is an actual pattern and whether has use cases that are helpful.

Comment: I think this should be asked in exchange. But Just my two cents about this.  I never see a pattern like this before, maybe the dev think this is clever and useful but if api calls are made automatically, how will you handle a route component that doesn't need to call to api? sure 404 will be thrown but that alone still consumes bandwith.

Comment: More when the promise rejects on 404 the route is aborted...